# Animation playing incorrectly when controlled through player

Tags: unity, animation

I have a 2D simple directional blend tree with 2 inputs, X and Y, for movement.

If i move the red dot in the inspector, the animations blend nicely. Same if i move the 2 input parameters in the animator. But if i press play and move the character with arrows, i can see the 2 parameter inputs  in the animator screen moving same as when i moved them with mouse, but the animation that is playing stays the same and the red dot that represents parameters in the inspector stays in the center (even though the parameters in the animator are moving).

I also tried using just 2 animations and blending between them, but turns out that doesn't work ether, even though animator shows that the correct animation should be playing. (if i press forward animator shows that forward animation is playing, but on scene the animation that is playing is like a blend at parameter value in the middle.

The animations were made in Blender as actions (if that's important).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had 2 problems.

1. I didn't set the Avatar under the animator.
2. I had 2 animator controllers, 1 on top level and 1 on character model. Apparently they didn't like each other.

After i set the avatar and deleted the animator on my character model, blending works perfectly.

Comment: Don't forget to come back in a couple of days to mark this answer as 'accepted' :)

Comment: LoL :D @AlexandreVaillancourt